# How to subtract a variable by itself (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, var, subtraction

I am trying to make a score counter app. That will allow the user to enter various scores. The problem is if the user change their score it will mess up the total. So the best way I can think of solving this problem is to subtract the scoreRed from itself to add 1. But the code is not compiling and I don't know why. So if scoreRed just started the score will 0 so I just have to add 1. But if scoreRed is greater than or equal to 1 i need it to be subtracted by itself to add one again so the total is just 1.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var scoreRed = 0

    @IBOutlet var highScoreLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var scoreDisplay2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var scoreDisplay: UIButton!

    @IBAction func add1(_ sender: Any) {
        if scoreRed == 0 {
            scoreRed += 1
        };
        if scoreRed >= 1 {
            //part not compiling below
           scoreRed = 0
          scoreRed += 1
            highScoreLabel.text = String(scoreRed)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Um, isn't first subtracting itself and then adding one the same as simply setting it to one?

Comment: How will you ever increment the score if you subtract the score from itself before adding 1?

Comment: Also, as long as the score is non-negative, all your current `add1` function is/would be doing is setting it to one.

Comment: Think I have figured it out look at my edited answer

Comment: Really though, why are you first setting it to zero and then adding one instead of just setting it to one in the first place? And what I said earlier also still stands: all you're doing is setting the score to one in any case other than when it was negative. If it's 0 in the beginning, it first gets incremented to 1 and then set to 0 and incremented to 1 again, and if it's more than 0 it's going to get set 0 and then incremented to 1. What you have there now is equal to `if scoreRed > -1 { scoreRed = 1 }`, excluding the label part of course.

Comment: @Roope, you should initialize at zero because most games begin with that score. But I'm most certainly *not* defending the code - nor the logic - of the OP! Use two functions - (a) incrementScore, you can even increment by more than one, and (b) resetScore where you simply change the score to either 0 or 1. (Ok, now that I've thought this through, **why** would you *reset* the score to one instead of zero. And yes, if you are really resetting to one, include something about that in your question.)